# Is there a simple alternative to GetModelAttemptedValue in HtmlHelpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create some HtmlHelper extensions and ran into a bit of a roadblock trying to get my extension methods to use attempted values defined by the ViewData.ModelState. The [`HtmlHelper.GetModelAttemptedValue()`](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/SourceControl/FileView.aspx?itemId=266468&changeSetId=17272) method is marked internal and isn't available to my extension methods. Is there a simple alternative in MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're going for here. Can't you just use the ViewData.ModelState available to the HtmlHelper and invoke TryGetValue on it yourself?  I understand that it not DRY, but it seems easier than trying to invoke the three-line method in the helper via reflection.

```
public static string MyHelper( this HtmlHelper helper, string modelKey)
{
     ModelState modelState;
     if (helper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue( modelKey, out modelState))
     {
        string attemptedValue = modelState.AttemptedValue;
     }
}
```